# Stopping a media player

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a media player on android phone.
This player starts based on some conditions, but I am unable to stop it (back button pressing doesn't work). Once the streamer who is sending the data stops, player stops too and crashes.

I want to stop the media player whenever I want by pressing the BACK button. can somebody tell me how to do so?

I have tried using methods like these, but they don't work!!

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
    {
        MediaPlayer.stop();
        MediaPlayer.release();
        finish();
    }


@Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
            finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put `super.onStop()` (super call) call in  your onstop method.And also i think you don't want to call finish () method twice.when you back the activity and the activity disappears and onStop called.you can remove onStop call from onBackPressed method.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
    MediaPlayer.release();
```

tou the activities onPause() method

Answer (score 0):

It should be smth like this:

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer = ...; //  define it somewhere

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    if(mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. will try them out.. 

can somebody help me how to keep screen on forever (avoiding unlocking during play) ?

Comment: make it another question..don't overlap the current problem